# Adding today's date to Oracle query results when using wildcard *

Tags: oracle, date, select

this might be a lack of very basic knowledge, but I just can't figure it out. Searching for the answer and trial and error haven't helped much.

Returning all recordsets from a table (`SELECT * FROM X`) --> no problem.
Returning today's date (`SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL`) --> no problem.

Returning all recordsets from the same table as well as today's date --> no luck. I have tried subselects, union, joins, with-statements, ... it's driving me nuts.

When I name the columns I want returned (`SELECT Columname1, Columnname2, to_char(sysdate....)`) it works. This problems seems to only occur when using wildcards.

How do I get Oracle to return "all columns", today's date"?

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, using `SELECT *` is generally not a good idea especially in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix the wildcard with the table name (or alias, if you've used one):

```
SELECT X.*, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS TODAYS_DATE FROM X
```

Using the wildcard is generally not considered a good idea, as you have no control over the order the columns are listed (if the table was built differently in different environments) and anyone consuming this output may be thrown if the table definition changes in the future, e.g. by adding another column. It's better to list all the columns individually.